# JavaScript / post gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the next post request:

```
POST /download HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
```

and the next request payload:

```
{"blabla":"toto"}
```

Now, In express module (node.js), I have the next:

```
app.post("/download", function(req, res){
    var parseJson = JSON.parse(req.body);

});
```

When I use JSON.parse, it gives me the next error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at c:\NodeI\node\express.js:161:19
    at callbacks (c:\NodeI\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
```

What can be the reason? I sent a JSON, why it doesn't parse it?

Comment: What is `console.log(req.body);`?

Comment: NO! What does it show in the console.

Comment: @epascarello: Nothing, It shown the error I wrote in the question

Comment: WHAT IS THE EXACT STRING you are trying to parse... There is no JSON.parse in what I am asking you. What you say you are sending down and what is actually being returned might be different.

Comment: @OrSmith — Put `console.log(req.body)` **before** `JSON.parse(req.body)` and tell us what the Node.js console (not the browser console) says.

Comment: @Quentin: {blabla: 'toto' } and in postman tool, I write {"blabla":"toto"} in the raw text input

Comment: @epascarello: {blabla: 'toto' } and in postman tool, I write {"blabla":"toto"} in the raw text input

Comment: Is there any hidden characters `console.log(escape(req.body));` Is it really missing the quotes because that is invalid JSON?

Comment: `{blabla: 'toto' }` isn't JSON … but it should complain about *unexpected token `b`*, not `o`.

Comment: @Quentin: so how I sent a json in the postman tool? what should I write in the input text?

Comment: @OrSmith — http://json.org/ will show you the syntax, http://jsonlint.com/ will let you test your JSON.

Comment: @Quentin: jsonlint.com say it a valid json...

Comment: @Quentin: I think it do some conversion of the json from the postman tool to the node.js, and I don't know why..

Comment: So stop telling us what you are typing into postman and start telling us what happens when you log the data using `console.log` in the place that we've told you to put it.

Comment: @Quentin: I told you. I wrote in postman {"blabla":"toto"}, which is a VALID JSON, but in the console I see { blabla: 'toto' }, which as you say, is not a valid. What else?

Comment: @Quentin: and with the escape command, I get the next output: %5Bobject%20Object%5D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON has already been parsed by the time it gets to `req.body`

`JSON.parse(req.body);` calls `toString()` on the JavaScript object, gets the string `[object Object]` and tries to parse that as JSON.

Just use `req.body` directly instead of running it through `JSON.parse`.